# Getting TypeError when trying to call multiline string in p5.js

Tags: javascript, string, typeerror, p5.js

I've been trying to work out a solution for taking single-line sentences (which I call "statements" in my code) and turning them into multiline sentences on my sketch. This question relates directly to [another question I posted on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37763435/split-single-line-string-into-multiline-string-in-javascript-p5-js), and I have been asked to post this new issue as a new question. 
The solution from [@KevinWorkman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37763435/split-single-line-string-into-multiline-string-in-javascript-p5-js?answertab=active#tab-top) got me the to this point. What's happening, though, is that I'm getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of undefined` when I try to run the program. The sketch loads, but when I click within the sketch to start the animation, I get that error. I think it's because my original `statements[]` array is now no longer of a type that can be called in my `draw()` function as it is. But I'm not knowledgeable enough to know what the issue is and I've looked through all of my JS and p5.js references and can't find a solution.

I'm posting my complete code in an effort to provide a minimal, complete, verifiable example. Despite the fact, as a writer, I find "minimal" and "complete" to be contradictory terms and, therefore, very confusing, here goes:

```
var clContext;
var speed = 0.8;
var statements = [];
var canvas;

//load the table of Clinton's statements and their polarity
function preload() {
  clContext = loadTable("cl_context_rev.csv", "header");
}

function setup() {
  canvas = createCanvas(680, 420);
  canvas.mousePressed(inWidth);
  background(51);
  noStroke();
  // iterate over the table rows called in 'preload()' from .csv file
  for (var i = 0; i < clContext.getRowCount(); i++) {
    var statement = clContext.get(i, "statement");
    var polarity = clContext.get(i, "polarity");
    }
    statements[i] = new Statement(polarity, statement);
  }

function draw() {
  if (mouseIsPressed) {
    background(51);
    for (var i = 0; i < statements.length; i++) {
      statements[i].display();
    }
  }
}

// Function to align statements, categories, and polarity
function Statement(polarity, statement) {
  // Break up single-line statements in order to display as multiline
  this.statement = split(statement, "<br>");
  this.polarity = polarity;
  this.x = random(width);
  this.y = random(height);
  this.dx = random(-speed, speed);
  this.dy = random(-speed, speed);
}
// Attach pseudo-class methods to prototype;
// Maps polarity to color and x,y to random placement on canvas
Statement.prototype.display = function() {
  this.x += this.dx;
  this.y += this.dy;

// Make statements reappear if they move off of the sketch display
  if(this.x > width+10){
    this.x = -10
  }
  if(this.y > height+10) {
    this.y = -10
  }
// Map positive/negative statements to colors
  if(this.polarity == -1){
    fill(229,121,59);
  }
  else if(this.polarity == 1){
    fill(97,93,178);
  }
  textSize(14);
  // Was directed to add both 'text' statements
  text(this.statement[0], this.x, this.y);
  text(this.statement[1], this.x, this.y+25);
}

// Create functions for hiding and showing statements
function inWidth() {
  width = width+5;
};
```

**Note:**

```
console.log(typeof this.statement[0])  // returns 'undefined'
console.log(typeof this.statement[1])  // returns 'undefined'
console.log(split(statement, "<br>"))  // returns 'undefined'  

console.log(statements) // returns 'object'
console.log(statements.length) // returns 20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 for (var i = 0; i < clContext.getRowCount(); i++) {
  var statement = clContext.get(i, "statement");
  var polarity = clContext.get(i, "polarity");
 }
 statements[i] = new Statement(polarity, statement);
```

I think the last line here should be inside the for loop for this to do what you want.

Your error means that you are trying to call the display() method on a value that's undefined. The only place you are calling the display() method is inside your draw() function, when you loop through the statements array. This means that at one point your statements array contains an undefined value. You can verify this, by console logging the array.

I suspect the reason why you have undefined values, is because when you attempt to fill up the statements array in the setup() function, you only call `statements[i] =` once, after your for loop has finished. At this point the value of `i` is whatever it was at the end of the for loop, therefore your statements array becomes an array, where the i-th element is whatever you've set it, all the previous elements are undefined.

correct code:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < clContext.getRowCount(); i++) {
  var statement = clContext.get(i, "statement");
  var polarity = clContext.get(i, "polarity");
  statements[i] = new Statement(polarity, statement);
  // OR statements.push(new Statement(polarity, statement));
 }
```

As a generic JavaScript coding style principle it's also a good idea to Array.push() instead of direct assignment to add items to an array.

Comment: I had it working with `statements[i]...` where it is. The problems began to occur when I split up the sentences into multiple lines. And, I'm afraid you're answer is not specific enough about `Array.push()` for me to know what you mean, as there are direct assignments in multiple places in my code. Tried [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to  glean your meaning. Note, however, I am working with p5.js, so `push()` [has a very specific use](http://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/push) and is not included as an `array` function. Thanks!

Comment: Added more details to my answer for clarification. I think what you have here is a simple typo/bug closing the for loop too early. I've checked your previous thread that you referenced, it was ok there, it's not ok here.

Comment: @LesleyLathrop You can safely call `statements.push()`, that's a different function than just calling `push()`. One is a P5 function, one is an array function. Why didn't you try it before saying it wouldn't work?

Comment: Thanks, @marton. You were correct insofar as that one line DID need to be where you said.So thanks for that and apologies for not trusting you in my first comment. That line had somehow gotten moved in my many attempts to resolve my problem. There were still other things I had to do to make my sketch work, but that's neither here nor there. I've posted a correct answer to my question above.

Answer (score 2):

Marton's answer is correct. I'm giving it an upvote, and I think you should accept it. But I'll try to expand on it, since I'm not sure you're understanding what it's saying.

Let's look at these lines:

```
for (var i = 0; i < clContext.getRowCount(); i++) {
    var statement = clContext.get(i, "statement");
    var polarity = clContext.get(i, "polarity");
}
statements[i] = new Statement(polarity, statement);
```

Please run through this code with some example data. Let's say that you have 3 rows.

- The first time you run through the loop, `i` is `0`. You get a `statement` and a `polarity`, but you don't do anything with them.
- The second time you run through the loop, `i` is `1`. You get a `statement` and a `polarity`, but you don't do anything with them.
- The third time you run through the loop, `i` is `2`. You get a `statement` and a `polarity`, but you don't do anything with them.
- The loop then exits. The `statement` and `polarity` variables go out of scope, so they're `undefined`. Same with the `i` variable.

Basically, that loop doesn't do anything. We then get to this line:

```
statements[i] = new Statement(polarity, statement);
```

But we know that `i`, `polarity`, and `statement` are undefined, so what you're really doing is this:

```
statements[undefined] = new Statement(undefined, undefined);
```

You say that this use to work, but I highly doubt that. What you're doing here doesn't make any sense. That statement definitely belongs inside the for loop, which is where it was in my answer to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37681588/p5-js-code-doesnt-throw-errors-but-wont-load-on-mouse-click).

But with how you have it now, nothing has been added to the array, except maybe something at an undefined index. So then we get to this line:

```
for (var i = 0; i < statements.length; i++) {
  statements[i].display();
}
```

Now, I'd bet that `statements.length` is 1, since you have something at one undefined index (maybe that index is the last value of `i`, I don't know). But you certainly don't have anything at index `0`. So then when you enter this loop, `i` is `0`, but you don't have anything at that index. In other words, `statements[0]` is undefined. So the inner line is really doing this:

```
undefined.display();
```

That's what's causing your error. Fixing the first problem will get rid of this error, since you'll actually be adding stuff to your array.

Also, please note that these lines:

```
// Was directed to add both 'text' statements
  text(this.statement[0], this.x, this.y);
  text(this.statement[1], this.x, this.y+25);
```

**This code I gave you was just an example.** You're going to have to do something more intelligent here. I was just showing you how you might access two indexes of the `statement` array. You'll have to actually check the length of this array and loop through the sentences to do something. What that is depends entirely on what you want to happen.

### On General Debugging

You seem to be having a lot of issues because you're trying to do everything at once. You'll save yourself a lot of headaches if you start working in smaller chunks. Instead of trying to add this functionality to your big main sketch, why don't you try to get a smaller example sketch working first? Try hardcoding the values so you can see exactly what's happening with the `split()` function. Use `println()` statements to understand what's going on. Trying to add everything all at once is just going to be confusing, for you and for us.

Please note that this is not a request for an MCVE (since you got angry last time I mentioned it), but honestly, the best thing you can do to help yourself is to start working in smaller steps.

You might also consider switching to regular Processing (Java mode), since it can give you more information on errors like this.

Comment: Actually, my bad, it did change things for me to put that up one level. I'm not sure how it got moved, as I don't recall doing it. But I looked at my Trump version, which I haven't touched throughout this process, and it was where you both said it should be. I'm afraid, however, that your suggested fix was much more complicated than it needed to be. I've posted the answer to my question below. And, for the record, PLEASE STOP saying I'm hostile or angry or yelling, because that could not be further from the truth. Is it not okay for a person to be direct without being accused of aggression?

Comment: @LesleyLathrop What about my answer as much more complicated than it needed to be? Marton told you to move the statement inside the loop, you said that wouldn't work, so I explained why the answer was indeed correct. Where is the answer you posted?

Comment: @LesleyLathrop I was talking about the tone you adopted on your previous quesiton when I asked you to post this follow-up question instead of modifying the existing question, which was already answered. That's how Stack Overflow works. You also reacted very negatively to the automatic expansion of `[mcve]` to [mcve] for some reason. I'm simply trying to avoid that reaction again. I'm here to help people, not get caught up in petty bickering fights. It's up to you how to proceed, but for the record, CAPITAL LETTERS MEAN YELLING ON THE INTERNET.

Comment: I'm going to post one last comment, then move on, as you have misinterpreted my comments and have no interest in accepting that I meant no harm or disrespect. For the record, capitalizing one or two words on the Internet ALSO means "emphasize this," because normally we don't have the option of bolding or italicizing things. I know we can do that here, but it's a habit that I'm used to. Lastly I, for one, have not been "bickering" or "fighting." I've been trying to explain my completely innocuous intent to you, but that's not something you seem willing to really hear. I, therefore, concede.

Comment: @LesleyLathrop I've answered 3/3 of your recent questions. I'm trying to help you. When I asked you to post a follow-up question instead of adding confusing edits, you said that you would NOT do that, adding that I "no longer need to remind you" about including a [mcve], even though that wasn't at all what I was doing. That's what I took as a hostile reply. If that wasn't your intention, that's fine. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to fix this with a few easy changes to the code. It seems so very obvious once I thought of it that I'm not at all sure why it took me so long to figure it out.

I started by making changes to the `setup()` code:

```
function setup() {
  canvas = createCanvas(680, 420);
  canvas.mousePressed(inWidth);
  background(51);
  noStroke();
  // iterate over the table rows called in 'preload()' from .csv file
  for (var i = 0; i < clContext.getRowCount(); i++) {
    var statement = clContext.get(i, "statement");
    var polarity = clContext.get(i, "polarity");
    var stateSplit = split(statement, "<br>");            // split the statements in setup to avoid issues elsewhere
      for (var j = 0; j < stateSplit.length; j++) {
        var stateJoin = join(stateSplit, "\n");           // join the statements, inserting a line break, to make a new array
      statements[i] = new Statement(polarity, stateJoin); // put this in the for loop (per @marton)
    }
    }
}
```

Then I modified my constructor and prototype display function as follows:

Got rid of this, since it only broke up the statements, but didn't join them:

```
  this.statement = split(statement, "<br>");
```

And replaced it with this:

```
  this.stateJoin = stateJoin;
```

Then I got rid of these:

```
text(this.statement[0], this.x, this.y);
text(this.statement[1], this.x, this.y+25);
```

And used this, instead:

```
    text(this.stateJoin, this.x, this.y)
```

And voila! Thanks to @marton and @KevinWorkman for suggestions.